# CurVe document class: alignment issue with subrubrics

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, document-classes, resume

I have the following issue with the alignment of subrubric titles in a résumé written with the CurVe class by Didier Verna.

When the rubric & subrubric titles are aligned left via options in the preamble:

```
\rubricalignment{l}%default: rubric titles centered
\subrubricalignment{l}%default: subrubric titles centered
```

the subrubric title ("Customer Services") shows an indent and is not aligned with the rubric title ("Professional Experience"). Screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Is there a way to align the subrubric title so **no indent** is produced? I am looking for a result / output in which rubric, subrubric title and entry are aligned consistently on the left-hand side.

I suspect this behaviour is due to the CurVe class being based on the LTXtable package by David Carlisle.  I played around with the options given in the documentation.

However, as this was not successful one may have to adapt the curve.cls, which looks quite daunting.

I put together a minimal working example:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,12pt,english,final]{curve}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{experience.tex}
\begin{rubric}{Professional Experience} %rubric title
\subrubric{Customer Services} % subrubric title
\entry*[Month/Year --- Month/Year]
        Customer Service Assistant at Fresh'n'Fruity, a bar / caf\'e{} serving organic smoothies, London, UK (xy hours/week)

\subrubric{Research} % subrubric title
\entry*[Month/Year --- Month/Year]
        Graduate Assistant, the Department for Science Fiction, Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry, UK (xy hours/week)

\entry*[MM/YY --- MM/YY]
        Research Intern with the ``Non-Violent Communication''-Project at the Peace Institute, Z\"urich, Switzerland

\end{rubric}
\end{filecontents}


\rubricalignment{l}%default: Rubriktitles centered
\subrubricalignment{l}%default: Subrubriktitles centered


\title{Graduate Student}
\subtitle{at the Peace Institute, Z\"urich, Switzerland}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\makerubric{experience} % Engagement, praktische Erfahrungen, vorherige Jobs

\end{document} % schliesst das Hauptdokument
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first line in the definition of `\@@subrubric` contains a trailing space, as can be seen here:

```
\def\@@subrubric#1{%
\rule{0bp}{\@beforespace}
{\@subrubricfont#1}
\@subrubricmark{#1}}
```

simply add `%` at the end of the line `\rule{0bp}{\@beforespace}` to prevent this trailing space; you can paste the following lines to the preamble of your document:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@@subrubric#1{%
\rule{0bp}{\@beforespace}%
{\@subrubricfont#1}
\@subrubricmark{#1}}
\makeatother
```

EDIT: I sent an e-mail to the class author, letting him know about this trailing space issue; he has confirmed that it was a bug.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is exactly what I was looking for. I did not want to bother Didier before I make sure this is a "real issue"!
@Audrey: Thank you for the edit to make it more readable!

Comment: @Amy: No problem! BTW: You should accept Gonzalo's answer by clicking on the check mark below the vote up/down arrows.

Comment: What to do if we don't have direct access to the package's code?